# Web Preview Limit Size

Tags: sharepoint-online, file, preview

My company is reviewing some solution, one of them is SharePoint.

I need to know the size limit of file that can be preview thru web viewer. For example, if I want to open and present PowerPoint file, what is the file size limit?

Can the web viewer/preview play video/sound and animation effects?

Comment: Are you talking about file viewer web part or a custom one?

Comment: file viewer web part. for example to open PPT file.

Answer (score 0):

File size limit in SharePoint online is **250 GB**.

Using SharePoint out of the box web parts/functionalities, you can preview the video/audio files.

For more information on SharePoint limits, check below documentation:

[SharePoint online limits](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/sharepoint-online-service-description/sharepoint-online-limits)

---

**Update from comments**:

There is no defined file size limit for file viewer web part in SharePoint.

Comment: I'm asking about preview limit on web viewer not the upload limit.

Comment: There is no defined file size limit for file viewer web part in SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

There seems not to be a clear limit declared by Microsoft about the size limit of file viewer web part. Per my test, a ppt file with 10 MB still works fine. How large is the file need to be handled?

Comment: Around 50 MB and > 1000 slides. Another product only handle 30 MB for viewer limit. That's why I need to confirm this because I am afraid there is also the viewer limit.

Comment: @user97069, well I think you need to have a try on it.